# How do I plot an "unarranged" array1 vs array2 in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have to plot two arrays:

array1= [ 0.6321    0.6640    0.6997    0.8574    0.8824    0.9222    0.0893    0.1310    0.1600    0.3251    0.4008   0.7528    0.7985    0.9871    0.0417    0.2209    0.2694]

array2 = [-40.8700  -46.9600  -47.3900  -19.8500  -13.4700   -5.7820   49.4100   58.6600   63.2000   45.6000   17.8800 -45.5000  -38.9800   27.2700   32.4500   63.3800   54.7800]

As you see, the first array is unarranged, so when I plot them together this mess happens:

[image]

Which is obvious, since plot() join the points together and they go back and forth. How I make this problem go away? I could order the arrays, but that's not what I want (I want to plot the point, (0.6321,-40.8700),(0.6640,-46.9600), etc.).

Comment: Are you just looking to plot a single dot at each point without any connecting lines? If so, try the command "plot(array1, array2, 'b.')".

Comment: @JimmyK4542 I want connecting lines, but I don't wanna them to go back and forth. Just joining the points, you know? That way I'll have a proper plot

Comment: I might be wrong, someone please correct me if I am, but this seems more appropriate for a programming/comp.sci exchange than it does the math exchange - since it's about programming and not really math. Just for next time.

Comment: What do you want connecting lines for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
[array1_sorted, array1_order] = sort(array1);
array2_sorted = array2(array1_order, : );
```